# Angular redirect on startup or writing wrong URL

Tags: angular, url, routes

i wanted to ask if its possible i could redirect every URL after "localhost:4200" to "localhost:4200/Welcome" if sth else is typed in the url. But afterwards it should be possible to reach other URL like "localhost:4200/Files", just not about passing the URL in the browser. Here my routes:

```
const routes: Routes = [
{ path: '', redirectTo: '/Welcome', pathMatch: 'full' },
{ path: 'Welcome', component: LoaderComponent},
{ path: 'Files', component: RowOfDataComponent },
{ path: 'Files/newFiles/:lid', component: DataArrowComponent },
{ path: '**', redirectTo: '/Welcome' }

];
```

So everytime someone trys to write sth else in the URL than "localhost:4200/Welcome" he shall be redirect to "localhost:4200/Welcome".

I would really appreciate your help, already thanks for reading through.

Comment: WHat you have does not work?

Comment: I can still access every Url if i just write it in the url of the browser. But i just want to get inside "localhost:4200/Welcome" at the beginning and everything else shall redirect there.

Comment: You can use guards and implement your logic into these guards to decide wether the url is accessible or not